# passing url parameters in rewritten url

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

It seems that parameters I am attempting to pass via a URL on a RewriteRule (using mod_rewrite on Apache) are not being processed by my PHP scripts.

If I have the URL: http://mysite/user/check/?username=peter or http://mysite/user/check/?email=peter@paul.com the username and email parameters are not being picked up.

RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/$  /member.php?mode=$1 [L]

Is there something I need to do with my rewritten URLs to catch those parameters I may tack on?

Answer (score 0):

Use [L,QSA] Keys - just all magic